# How to split view into several controllers in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have one view page with followed structure:

```
==============================================
| Config   |       Map        |       Charts |
===============================================
|          |                  |              | 
|          |                  |              |
```

The `$routeProvider` for this page looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('cntsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap','LocalStorageModule']); 

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/mapboard/',
                  {templateUrl: 'app/partials/cnts.html', 
                    controller: 'CntsCtrl'});                
        }]);
```

`cnts.html`:

```
<div ng-include=" '/app/partials/config.html' "></div>

<div ng-include=" '/app/partials/map.html' "></div>

<div ng-include=" '/app/partials/chart.html' "></div>
```

All 3 HTMLs have the same scope (a.e. under one controller named `'CntsCtrl'`).

I want to split scope to 3 controllers.

My problem is if I'll add `ng-controller` for each HTML (config, map, chart) , the controllers actually will be children of `CntsCtrl`. And scope hierarchy will be:

```
rootScope 
          -> CntsCtrl
                      -> ConfigCtrl  
                      -> MapCtrl  
                      -> ChartCtrl
```

But I want:

```
rootScope
          -> ConfigCtrl  
          -> MapCtrl  
          -> ChartCtrl
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply omit `controller: 'CntsCtrl'` part from your route config.

`ng-view` directive, which is used in pair with $routeProvider, [does not require <sup>source</sup>](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.10/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js#L261) a route to have a controller.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Stewie, remove the controller part from the route, leaving just:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/mapboard/',
                  {templateUrl: 'app/partials/cnts.html'});                
}]);
```

And then, in your subsequent htmls you put the controller on each one:

config.html

```
<div ng-controller="ConfigCtrl">
    <!-- Stuff -->
</div>
```

map.html

```
<div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <!-- Stuff -->
</div>
```

chart.html

```
<div ng-controller="ChartCtrl">
    <!-- Stuff -->
</div>
```